# Gulp - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yashraj\Desktop\my-reporter\lib'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, filesystems, testcafe

I am writing Testcafe reporter plugin . i am running Vscode and cmd as admin then also i am getting this error `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yashraj\Desktop\my-reporter\lib'` . after running `gulp build` it is failing

Error -

```
`PS C:\Users\yashraj\Desktop\my-reporter> gulp test
[14:37:50] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\my-reporter\gulpfile.js
[14:37:50] Starting 'test'...
[14:37:50] Starting 'clean'...
[14:37:50] Finished 'clean' after 19 ms
[14:37:50] Starting 'build'...
[14:37:50] 'build' errored after 437 ms
[14:37:50] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\yashraj\Desktop\my-reporter\lib'
[14:37:50] 'test' errored after 466 ms
`
```

i am removed path from .npmrc file and set path as global NODEJS then also it is not working.

I want to solve this error so, i can run `gulp build` and `gulp test`

Comment: It might be caused by your antivirus software. Try to disable it.

Comment: Thank you for reply . i am not using any antivirus

Comment: You can also try to clear npm cache `npm cache clean` or even `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I tried so many times even i removed set path of local nodejs to global nodejs

Comment: You mentioned that you are using VSCode. Does the error occur only when VSCode is opened? What if you close it, wait for a moment and try to run tests from cmd?

Comment: no i am encountering same error when i am using cmd

Comment: Check the Permissions setting for the admin in the folder (Right Click on a folder > Properties > Security Tab > Edit...). You might need to give the corresponding permissions to a user.

Comment: i done this several times then also i am getting error

Comment: Can you provide your reporter project? It might help us determine the cause of the problem.